# Sort with assumptions

Tags: symbolic, list-manipulation, sorting

I have a list which looks like this

`list = {0, Subscript[x,7], -Subscript[x,3]-Subscript[x,9], -Subscript[x,9]};`

and all the $x_i$'s are positive semidefinite (i.e. nonnegative) real numbers. I would like to be able to sort this into

`sortedlist = {-Subscript[x,3]-Subscript[x,9], -Subscript[x,9], 0, Subscript[x,7]}`

How do I achieve this? I tried

`Assuming[Subscript[x,3] > 0 && Subscript[x,7] > 0 && Subscript[x,9] > 0, Sort[list]]`

But this obviously does not work. In general, I'd like to be able to impose more constraints on the $x_i's$ when they're being sorted.

Comment: An interesting idea, but a symbolic list where you have an ordering for all the elements is rare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
sortWithAssumptions[list_, assum_] := Module[{order},
    order[a_, b_] := Simplify[a < b, assum];
    Sort[list, order]
]
```

For your example:

```
sortWithAssumptions[
    {0,Subscript[x,7],-Subscript[x,3]-Subscript[x,9],-Subscript[x,9]},
    Subscript[x,3]>0&&Subscript[x,7]>0&&Subscript[x,9]>0
] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{-x_3-x_9,-x_9,0,x_7\right\}$

Another example:

```
sortWithAssumptions[
    {0,Subscript[x,7],-Subscript[x,3]-Subscript[x,9],-Subscript[x,9], Subscript[x,9]},
    Subscript[x,3]>0&&Subscript[x,7]>0&&Subscript[x,9]>0&&Subscript[x,7]<Subscript[x,9]
] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{-x_3-x_9,-x_9,0,x_7,x_9\right\}$

Comment: Thank you, Carl!

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
list[[Ordering[list /. _Subscript -> 1]]]
```

> {-Subscript[x, 3] - Subscript[x, 9], -Subscript[x, 9], 0, Subscript[x, 7]}

So basically we sort it the way it would be sorted with all subscripts == 1.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work like a charm, but can you shed some light on why?

Comment: @leastaction just take a look at `list /. _Subscript -> 1` and at `Ordering[list /. _Subscript -> 1]`.

Comment: I see, so you basically assigned the value $x_i = 1$ to each $x_i$. It works in this case, but generically, $x_i$'s may be different.

Comment: @leastaction sure, which means there isn't only one correct answer and every valid within constraints is correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
Sort[list, TrueQ@Simplify[#1 < #2, _Subscript > 0] &]

(* Out: {-Subscript[x, 3] - Subscript[x, 9], -Subscript[x, 9], 0, Subscript[x, 7]} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, we can use `RankedMin` and `FullSimplify` to get the answer you seek

```
Assuming[
 Subscript[x, 3] > 0 && Subscript[x, 7] > 0 && Subscript[x, 9] > 0, 
 FullSimplify[Table[RankedMin[list, i], {i, 1, Length[list]}]]]
(* {-Subscript[x, 3] - Subscript[x, 9], -Subscript[x, 9], 0, Subscript[x, 7]} *)
```

This has the advantage of not returning a (potentially) wrong answer if the sort order is uncertain.